# Is this kernel proper?

Tags: svm

[image]

I think it is proper as it follows the rule that K(x1,x2) = f(x1)f(x2)

Also they are both a function of only one of the points in the kernel respectively. Finally the product of two valid kernels is hence a proper kernel.

I was wondering whether my reasoning was correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $g(\mathbf{x})=(x_1^3+3x_2-\sqrt{x_3})^2$, for $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^3$. Then $K(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})=g(\mathbf{x})g(\mathbf{y})$. For $\mathbf{x}_1,\dots,\mathbf{x}_k\in\mathbb{R}^3$, we have that $\Sigma=(\sigma_{ij})=(K(\mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{x}_j))$ can be written as the outer product $\Sigma=\mathbf{u} \mathbf{u}^\top$, where $\mathbf{u} = (g(\mathbf{x}_1),\dots,g(\mathbf{x}_k))^\top$. Hence, for any non null $\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{R}^3$, we have $\mathbf{y}^\top\Sigma \mathbf{y}=\mathbf{y}^\top \mathbf{u} \mathbf{u}^\top \mathbf{y} = (\mathbf{u}^\top \mathbf{y})^2\geq 0$.